# Class variables in JavaScript and setInterval

Tags: javascript, object, timer, setinterval, anonymous-function

Since I need to pass an anonymous function to `setInterval` if I want parameters, I tried using the below code. Originally I had it calling `this.countUp`, but as that returned `NaN` I did some reading and found the `.call(this)` solution on SO. However, when I combined that with the anonymous function (which I admit I'm a bit foggy on), I'm now getting `TypeError: this.countUp is undefined` in Firebug.

I suppose I don't need to make `count` accessible, nor the `playBeep` method, but let's pretend I wanted to so that I can understand what I'm doing wrong with this code.

```
    function workout() {
        var beep = new Audio("beep1.wav");
        this.timerWorkout; //three timers in object scope so I can clear later from a different method
        this.timerCounter; 
        this.timerCoolDown;
        this.count = 0;

        this.startWorkout = function() {
            alert(this.count);
            this.timerWorkout = setTimeout(this.playBeep, 30 * 1000); //workout beep - 30 seconds
            this.timerCounter = setInterval(function() {this.countUp.call(this)}, 1000); //on screen timer - every second

        }

        this.startCoolDown = function() {
            this.timerCoolDown = setTimeout(this.playBeep, 10 * 1000); //cooldown beep - 10 seconds
        }

        this.playBeep = function() {
            beep.play(); //plays beep WAV
        }

        this.countUp = function() {
            this.count++;
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = this.count; 
        }

    }

    var workout1 = new workout()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `startWorkout` use `bind(this)` :

```
this.timerCounter = setInterval(function() {this.countUp()}.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: :) Read-up on `bind()`, you will use it a lot.

Comment: Perfecto ... here's the link to info on bind ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2):

What happens is setInterval is changing the value of `this` inside the function you provide for it to call. You need to store `this` in a separate variable to prevent it from getting overridden.

```
function workout() {
    var self = this;
    // ...

     this.startWorkout = function() {
            alert(this.count);
            this.timerWorkout = setTimeout(self.playBeep, 30 * 1000); // this method works
            this.timerCounter = setInterval(function() {self.countUp}, 1000); // so does this one
     }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, OK. It works fine with the `playBeep` method because there are no parameters. I'm also going to try the `bind` solution posted above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the variable scope in js is limited on function. So when you are trying to use `this` inside a nested function, you get a link to another object. Create a variable `var that = this;` into a higher-level function, and then use it in any nested function that would refer you to the correct context.